# Python | Scatterplot is not showing

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, pca

I am performing PCA on my data set and I could get the right results. But when I am trying to visualize the PCA, it doesn't showing.
Here is my try:

```
#Import dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv', names=['0','1','2','3','target'],header=0)
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, -1].values


#PCA
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components = 2)
X = pca.fit_transform(X)
principalDf = pd.DataFrame(data = X, columns = ['principal component 1', 
'principal component 2'])
finalDf = pd.concat([principalDf, dataset['target']], axis = 1)

#Visualizing 
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (8,8))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) 
ax.set_xlabel('Principal Component 1', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_ylabel('Principal Component 2', fontsize = 15)
ax.set_title('2 component PCA', fontsize = 20)
targets = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
colors = ['r', 'g', 'b', 'hotpink']
for target, color in zip(targets,colors):
    indicesToKeep = finalDf['target'] == target
    ax.scatter(finalDf.loc[indicesToKeep, 'principal component 1']
           , finalDf.loc[indicesToKeep, 'principal component 2']
           , c = color
           , s = 50)
ax.legend(targets)
ax.grid()
```

But this is not  working and I can not figure it out. How can I fix this?
[image: The Visualization result]
[image: Part of the PCA processed data]

Comment: Could you provide an example of what data looks like in `['principal component 1', 
'principal component 2']` columns?

Comment: @dm2 Thank you. I just got this. The plot if in the range -0.04 to 0.04 (y axis) but principal component 2 is in -2.3 to 6.7 range. same for the X axis. how can I fix this?

Comment: I have no idea why you have this problem, since you're not specifying the axes limits anywhere in the code provided (and so they should adjust automatically), so you could try adjusting them via `ax.set_xlim(-10,10)` and `ax.set_ylim(-10,10)` (note: you might want to choose different values depending on your data)

Comment: @dm2 The plot is not showing even though I had added the axis limits.

Comment: Can you please check that your `target` column is `str` type (noted as `object` in `finalDf.info()`) and not numerical? Otherwise, you're using `str` type as targets, but your targets are actually numerical, so you're not plotting anything.

Comment: @dm2 yes! Thank yo for showing it. Yes my target column has a numerical value.  Can you please show me how to change it to have a  numerical value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are indexing your `finalDf` to get slices of DataFrame where `target` column values are the same as a single `target` from the list `targets = ['1', '2', '3', '4']`.

Since the values in your `target` column are not `str` type, but numerical type, there is no data that satisfies this condition:

```
'1' != 1
'2' != 2
'3' != 3
'4' != 4
```

And thus no data is plotted.

To get the slices you want, instead of `targets = ['1', '2', '3', '4']` you should use numerical values as target:

```
targets = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```